# How to select unique record in a Microsoft Access table?

Tags: ms-access, select

I have an Access table that has a few records as follows (ID, color):

```
1 red
1 blue
2 blue
3 white
3 yellow
3 red
```

How do I create a query so that only record with ID 2 is returned? I don't want to select IDs 1 and 3 because they each have multiple records in this table. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT * 
FROM  tbl 
GROUP BY ID
HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
```